# Retrieving value from radio button inside a jinja2 loop and pass it to different forms in flask

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2

I am currently creating a webpage that lists out every grocery items, type, and prices in a table. The data is stored in a mongoDB collection. I also have radio buttons right next to each entry that enables me to select a specific entry and do operations with it, such as modify entry, delete entry. The webpage looks something like this:
[image]

Right now I have two route in my backend, delete and edit and I want to call them based on the button I pressed. However, because the data is printed in a loop, I am having issues retrieving the data. Below is the html snippet of what I wanted to achieve.

```
<form action="{{url_for('grocery.delete', ID = grocery.ID)}}">
<button type = "submit" name = "action_button">Delete </button>
</form>
<form action="{{url_for('grocery.edit', ID = grocery.ID)}}">
<button type = submit>Edit </button>
</form>

<thead>
        <th>Select</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Grocery</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Price</th>
  
</thead>
<tbody>
        {% for key, value in db.items() %}
        {% for items in value %}
        <tr>
            <td><input type = "radio" name = "selection" id = "selection" value = "{{items['_id']}}"></td>   
            <td>{{items["_id"]}}</td>
            <td>{{items["grocery"]}}</td>
            <td>{{items["type"]}}</td>
            <td>{{items["price"]}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}

</tbody>
```

**Right now my biggest issue is how do I assign/pass the value selected on radio buttons to the field `grocery.ID` and use the selected value outside of the jinja2 loop?**

While I know I can use one single `<form>` tag to encapsulate the entire html then do a `request.args.get` in my flask code to get selected value on radio button, I feel like this defeats the purpose of making specific routes for edit and delete. Also because I plan to use bootstrap modal for edit, I don't think I am able to use this method without making the code overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `url_for('grocery.delete', ID = grocery.ID)` is that you don't know on the backend that what will the user select in the future on the frontend. But with a little JavaScript we can solve this.

For example with [Alpine.js](https://alpinejs.dev/start-here) it's quite simple, we just need a `selection` Alpine.js variable that we can use to update the button's URL with the actual selected item's ID. See a minimal demo below (assuming the endpoint URL is like `/grocery/delete/42`):

```html
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div x-data="{ selection: '1' }">
  <form :action="`/grocery/delete/${selection}`">
    <button type = "submit" name = "action_button">Delete </button>
  </form>
  <form :action="`/grocery/edit/${selection}`">
    <button type = submit>Edit </button>
  </form>
  
  <div x-text="`Delete URL: /grocery/delete/${selection}`"></div>
  <div x-text="`Edit URL: /grocery/edit/${selection}`"></div>
  
  
  <input type="radio" name="selection" x-model="selection" value="1" />Selection #1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="selection" x-model="selection" value="2" />Selection #2<br>
  <input type="radio" name="selection" x-model="selection" value="3" />Selection #3<br>
</div>
```